# How can I find rollup 3.1.0 update error?

Tags: javascript, package, babeljs, rollup

1. i want to install `rollup-plugin-visualizer` but its need to update rollup.
2. updated rollup from `1.8.0` to `3.1.0`

   got error

   ```
   [!] RollupError: Node tried to load your configuration file as CommonJS even though it is likely an ES module. To resolve this, change the extension of your configuration to ".mjs", set "type": "module" in your package.json file or pass the "--bundleConfigAsCjs" flag.
   ```
3. delete node-modules folder and package-lock.json and install again `npm i`

got error

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: @bet-core/ui@2.4.0
npm ERR! Found: rollup@3.1.0
npm ERR! node_modules/rollup
npm ERR!   dev rollup@"^3.1.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer rollup@">=0.60.0 <3" from rollup-plugin-babel@4.4.0
npm ERR! node_modules/rollup-plugin-babel
npm ERR!   dev rollup-plugin-babel@"^4.3.2" from the root project
```

`rollup-plugin-babel` npm page says !!!

This package has been deprecated and is no longer maintained. Please use @rollup/plugin-babel.

4. i have delete `rollup-plugin-babel` then install `@rollup/plugin-babel.`
   now i got this error

```
[!] RollupError: Node tried to load your configuration file as CommonJS even though it is likely an ES module. To resolve this, change the extension of your configuration to ".mjs", set "type": "module" in your package.json file or pass the "--bundleConfigAsCjs" flag.
    Original error: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

can someone tell me where to look for this error solutions?

Comment: i dont want to set "type": "module"

Comment: "rollup": "^2.79.1" works with cjs. Version 3.0.0 and above throws the error posted on this question. If I use the --bundleConfigAsCjs flag. My library bundle doesn't work with Next.JS

Answer (score 11, accepted):

i have find the solution.
At first changed format from `'esm'` to `'cjs'` in `rollup.config.js`

```
export default {
    ...
    output: [
             {
                format: 'cjs',
                ...
            },
       
    ]
};
```

then `rollup.config.js` changed to `rollup.config.mjs`

Comment: This worked, but I ended up using the `--bundleConfigAsCjs`  flag. This way, I could keep the default config name `rollup.config.js` :)

Comment: @widepeepohappy thank you it's helped me too
```"build": "rm -rf dist && rollup -c --bundleConfigAsCjs && node ./scripts/copyFiles.js",```

Comment: And what if you want both an `esm` and `cjs` output?

Answer (score 5):

Hi man I have the same issue running "npm run rollup"

RollupError: Node tried to load your configuration file as CommonJS even though it is likely an ES module. To resolve this, change the extension of your configuration to ".mjs", set "type": "module" in your package.json file or pass the "--bundleConfigAsCjs" flag.

**What I found:**

- https://github.com/rollup/rollup/issues/4619
- https://github.com/rollup/rollup/pull/4621
  -You can try out this pull request locally by installing Rollup vi
  npm install rollup/rollup#esm-load-config
  or load it into the REPL:
  https://rollupjs.org/repl/?pr=4621
- this might work either: https://github.com/rollup/rollup/blob/master/docs/01-command-line-reference.md

Answer (score 2):

If you're using node v14 upgrade it to v16, this works in my case, especially when you run Rollup in GitHub Action:

```
name: Release @vueup/vue-quill

on: 
  push: 
    branches: 
      - alpha
      - beta
      - master
    paths: 
      - 'packages/vue-quill/**'
jobs: 
  release: 
    name: Build and release
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps: 
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: 16
      - name: Install root deps
        run: npm ci
      - name: Install package deps
        working-directory: packages/vue-quill
        run: npm ci
      - name: Release package
        working-directory: packages/vue-quill
        run: npx ts-node ../../scripts/release.ts vue-quill
        env: 
          GH_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GH_TOKEN }}
          NPM_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.NPM_TOKEN }}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can downgrade to version 2.77.4-1. That version works for me.